# Shared preferences don't persist when app restarts

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am making an app where I want the user to be able to save their preferences. I am using the shared preferences like so:

```
private void writeSettings(String val){
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString("status", val).commit();
        Log.d("stat", val);
}
```

This works fine, and reading works great. If I close the app out and restart it, it's gone. Aren't preferences supposed to be saved unless the app is deleted?

Comment: where do you call writeSettings method?

Comment: shared preferences data is removed  only when try to clear application data manually.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that commit doesn't work when chained.

Comment: @raybritton that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you call writeSettings method? If in onStop() or onDestroy(), sometimes these don't get called. If this is the case add your code to onPause().

Other than that you can try saving them not in chain, like this:

```
// save string in sharedPreferences 
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("some_key", value); // here value is the string you want to save
editor.commit();                    

// restore string in sharedPreferences (usually you have this onCreate method) 
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String string = settings.getString("some_key", "");
```

Comment: its not an on destroy, its basically to stop/start a broadcast receiver so they pretty much can turn it on off.

Comment: you cant chain in java? (im used to web programming)

Comment: worked.. im wondering why chaining the methods caused an issue?

Comment: @Marko Niciforovic: In which method are you saving the shared preferences? i tried in onDestroy(), onPause(), onStop(). None of them are saving the  data.:(

Comment: @MAHANTESH you can save them in any function you want, just make sure that function gets called. You can make sure if your function gets called by adding a log and check your logcat. If log is there, then you are doing something wrong with shared preferences. :)

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic : hey thanks and i will check it by adding the logs, but can you tell me till when shared preferences are stored in mobile? till i uninstall the app? or till i delete the app data? or till i force stop it?how actually things work in shared preferences ?

Comment: SharedPreferences are XML file stored in private part of your app. Data is saved untill you delete the app or clear data of the app in settings - > application manager..

Answer (score 1):

You have to use commit() method to save your changes in consistent state in sharedprefernce.

Refer this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit%28%29

Comment: i did use commit(). the problem was i was chaining the methods.